# JQuery UI question, how do you add variables into the dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

```
$('.openDialog').click(function(event){
        var width=$(this).attr('width');
        var height=$(this).attr('height');
        alert(width + ' ' + height);
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true});
        $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'width', width);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        $('#dialog p').load('http://pagetoload.com/page.html .content');
});
```

As you can see above i'm trying to open a dialog box with a passed in parameter of width and height, however when I try and pass in the value of width on this line:

$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'width', width);

it doesn't work, any ideas why or how to get around that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, you have to put [] around it for some reason.

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'width', [width]);
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'height', [height]);
```

instead of

```
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'width', width);
$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'height', height);
```

Very interesting

Answer (score 1):

```
var width=$(this).attr('width'); //width = 300px
```

would yields you a variable width of say 300px instead of 300 as what the .dialog options need.

Try doing a parseInt:

```
width = parseInt($(this).attr('width')); //width = 300
```

Then only pass it to the .dialog option.